# How can i get computer name in .net?

Tags: .net, computer-name

I want to get the computer name in the live.means suppose if any one open my site i want to get his system name. In a work group also i want to get the name of system not workgroup name.

I have did so many link but all are working for local when i host that won't.

Here is my code:

```
UserName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

In the local it is working when i post that into server That will not get the system name. Please help me.

Comment: I tried this link but that will not work on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand you well, but there are many ways to do so, and here's what i know:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

or

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
Environment.UserName;
```

Comment: No Man, That will not work.